# getting back just axios data in redux thunk not a array list

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I want to get back data from axios Api into redux thunk just like this one

```
  axios
      .post(`/metrics`, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
```

insted of data array how do I that

Comment: you should dispatch your redux thunk instead of the console log

Comment: Can you share more of your code so we can help you better